# Getting weird characters in Git for Windows bash when running cypress from command line

Tags: cypress, git-for-windows

I'm using cypress for test automation and when running a test spec from the Git for Windows bash terminal I get weird characters in the results output:

cypress spec run in Git for Windows bash -

[image: screenshot]

If I run cypress from a Windows command prompt the output characters are correct:

cypress spec run in Windows Command Prompt -

[image: screenshot]

I'm using Windows 7, cypress 5.1.0, and Git for Windows 2.28.0 with mintty 3.2.0

Any thoughts on how to correct this?

Comment: Looks like you have this issue: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2806

Comment: I am having the same problem while running the test in git bash now running the latest version 5.1.0

Comment: @digijay That is exactly the issue. Thanks! How can I mark this answered and give you "credit" for the answer?

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help! If you want to give something back to the community then try to answer some questions here  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The issue is described in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2806).

The problem is that Cypress is sending UTF-8 encoded text through its `stdout` which is mangled by Windows before being received by Mintty (which is what hosts `bash` and runs `git` on Windows).

I understand that Mintty doesn't yet instruct Windows to not mangle the `stdout` it processes - (`cmd.exe` does, however, which is why it works there) - but we can do that ourselves by changing our Windows OEM Code Page setting using the `chcp` program (located at `C:\Windows\System32\chcp.com` and yes, that's a `.com`, not `.exe`). You can add a command to your `.bashrc` file so it will always run when you fire up Mintty:

1. Open mintty on Windows - presumably this starts a bash shell.
2. Go to your home directory (i.e. `cd ~`)
3. Open or create a `.bashrc` file.
4. Put this in the file (update the path to your `chp.com` program as appropriate):

   ```
   /c/Windows/System32/chcp.com 65001
   ```
5. Then restart the terminal window and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

As both @digijay and @Dai replied above the cause of the issue is described here https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2806

The issue was resolved with the next release of git-for-windows. Prior to the fix being released, I solved the issue for myself by simply running this at the bash command line before running my cypress run command:

```
> cmd //c chcp 65001
```